# iPhone .bashrc not working properly

Tags: iphone, linux, bash, ssh, jailbreak

**SOLVED: I had the wrong line endings selected in my text editor**

I tried to get a `.bashrc` going on my iPhone, just for fun. After adding `source /var/root/.bashrc` to my `/etc/profile` file I get this every time I log into a terminal emulator, local or over SSH.

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
>
```

My cursor overwrites the '>' everytime I type

The contents of `/var/root/.bashrc`

```
alias install='apt-get install'
alias remove='apt-get remove'
alias aptsearch='apt-cache search'

alias respring='killall SpringBoard'
alias safemode='touch /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.saurik.mobilesubstrate.dat && killall SpringBoard'
alias shutdown='halt'
alias poweroff='halt'

alias ls='ls -group-directories-first -Ah'
alias lsl='ls -Ah1 --group-directories-first'

alias killall='killall -v'

alias reload='source /var/root/.bashrc'

export PS1='\w> '

clear
```

The contents of `/etc/profile`

```
export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games'
export PS1='\h:\w \u\$ '
umask 022

for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        . $i
    fi
done
source /var/root/.bashrc
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

**SOLVED: I had the wrong line endings selected in my text editor**

Answer (score 0):

Try manually executing the script and taking a look at the output. You should get a line number to help you along.

Comment: It was the line endings that I had selected in my text editor. But thanks for your adivdce!

Comment: @cat_ears Yeah, line endings suck.